# Multiple change of lotus type groups

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

maybe someone once wrote a script for mass change of lotus type groups? Mass but not all, only grups with first two characters begins on ('GD') i need change mostly type from mail only (3) to Multipurpose (0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select the groups, create an agent with this code, that runs on selected documents:

```
FIELD GroupType := "0";
```

If you really want to do the selection in your agent, then let it run on "all documents in view" and add a selection before the action:

```
SELECT @Begins( ListName ; "GD" );
FIELD GroupType := "0";
```

As this will run a lot slower I would manually select the groups and use the first agent as selecting is as easy as setting the cursor to the first group with "GD", then scroll down to the last one and click it while holding the Shift- Key.